# How specify mysql storage engine type when using DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, datamapper

When defining simple DataMapper resource, it sets default storage engine to InnoDB, but I need MyISAM, any way to override InnoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way using the dm-mysql-adapter but [dm-mysql](https://github.com/neovintage/dm-mysql) looks promising.

> I had originally submitted a request
>   to the DataMapper team to include an
>   option to allow MySQL database users
>   the ability to specify table options
>   in their DataMapper models. My needs
>   were around data warehousing and I
>   wanted to use a different storage
>   engine like Infobright. Unfortunately
>   this request was denied because
>   dm-core could have ended up looking
>   like spaghetti if my request were
>   approved. Mind you I'm oversimplifying
>   the argument, but I understood where
>   they were coming from. As a result, I
>   bring you dm-mysql!

- [Want more control over your database tables in DataMapper?](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2009/02/want-more-control-over-your-database.html)